# This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes

Tags: iphone, ios9, xcode7-beta4

I get this log in the console when I am running my application in is simulator. Haven't seen this in iOS 8. I am not quite sure whats causing this. Has anyone else come across the same issue and if so how was it fixed? or is there any help anyone can provide in regards to this?

Comment: so .. https://github.com/nrbrook/NBUIKitMainThreadGuard

Comment: Refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28302019/6521116)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075072/8537648

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Do not change UI from anything but the main thread. While it may appear to work on some OS or devices and not others, it is bound to make your application unstable, and crash unpredictably.

If you must respond to a notification, which *can* happen in the background, then ensure `UIKit` invocation **takes place on the main thread**.

You at least have these 2 options:

## Asynchronous Dispatch

Use `GCD` *(Grand Central Dispatch)* if your observer can be notified on any thread. You can listen and do work from any thread, and encapsulate UI changes in a `dispatch_async`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // Do UI stuff here
}
```

When to use `GCD`? When you do not control who sends the notification. It can be the OS, a Cocoapod, embedded libraries, etc. Using `GCD` will woke anytime, every time. Downside: You find yourself re-scheduling the work.

---

## Listen on Main Thread

Conveniently, you can specify on which thread you want the observer to be notified, **at the time you are registering** for notifications, using the `queue` parameter:

```
addObserverForName:@"notification"
    object:nil
    queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note){
        // Do UI stuff here
    }
```

When to *observe on main thread*? When you are both registering and registered. Bu the time you respond to the notification, you are already where you need to be.

---

## Post Notification On Main Thread

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(postNotification:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Hybrid solution which **does not guarantee** that the observer is only invoked from said method. It allows for lighter observer, at the cost less robust design. Only mentioned here as a solution *you should probably avoid*.

Comment: so we do make a couple of updates on the UI when we hear a notification, so are you saying that I need to make those updates inside "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()"?

Comment: Exactly. I have added examples.

Comment: alrighty, trying this now and will choose yours as an answer if it fixed it :D

Comment: why was this not required in iOS 8?, why does this happen in iOS 9?

Comment: It was best practice well before iOS 8 - Apple has just chosen iOS 9 to start warning of improper updates, and, as the error states, will soon being disallowing UI updates on a background thread entirely.

Comment: Do you know how can i find where is the problem? For me the changes before the warning were to make a scrollview and add the controller.view to it, and some more to support the change but i still can't find it.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/149202/cristi-b%c4%83lu%c8%9b%c4%83: you may want to ask a new question and post some code

Comment: Thanks. This is a great answer!

Comment: Great. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34540787/218152 for a discussion on posting notifications on the main thread.

Answer (score 20):

Swift 3.0

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
}
```

Answer (score 5):

All UI part updation you need to move into MAIN thread of App.

I was calling a **createMenuView()** into background and i got below error

**"This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes"**

So I called above  method into Main thread Using

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    }
```

in SWIFT 3.0 and Xcode 8.0

Correct code written below :

```
RequestAPI.post(postString: postString, url: "https://www.someurl.com") { (succeeded: Bool, msg: String, responceData:AnyObject) -> () in

        if(succeeded) {
            print(items: "User logged in. Registration is done.")

            // Move to the UI thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: { () -> Void in

                //Set User's logged in
                Util.set_IsUserLoggedIn(state: true)
                Util.set_UserData(userData: responceData)
                self.appDelegate.createMenuView()

            })

        }
        else {
            // Move to the UI thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: { () -> Void in
                let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: JJS_MESSAGE, message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alertcontroller.title = "No Internet"
                alertcontroller.message = FAILURE_MESSAGE
                self.present(alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Should try Symbolic Breakpoint to detect the issue:-[image]

Symbol:

```
[UIView layoutIfNeeded]
```

Condition:

```
!(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]
```

Then put your UI Update code in main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {}
```

Comment: Great answer to find the problematic piece of code. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have code that updates the UI layout from a background thread.
Changing the operation queue that you run your code on does not need to be explicit. For example NSURLSession.shared() does not use the main queue when making new requests. 
To ensure that your code runs on the main thread, I'm using NSOperationQueue's static method mainQueue().

Swift:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(){
    //Do UI stuff here
}
```

Obj-C:

```
[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    //Do UI stuff here
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue is happened in my case,i have to change the code in following way then it works fine.
In `ViewDidLoad`,call this method by using `main thread`,

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setUpTableRows) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```