# UIButton won't enable under some circumstances

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

in my application i'm using a `UIButton` (myButton) wich i added via `Storyboard`.
So, when tapping the button an `IBAction` gets called:

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender{
    [myCustomClass doSomeCrazyStuff];
    [sender setEnabled:NO];
}
```

As you can see, i'm calling a method from `myCustomClass` ( `myCustomClass` is a REST-Client for my web-service).
The `viewController` the button lays in is delegate of `myCustomClass`.
There are two delegate methods implemented, one for *success* and one for *error*.

```
-(void)requestSucceeded{  
    /* If the request succeeded i want the button to be enabled again, and it's selected  
       state inverted */  
    NSLog(@"This gets called");
    [myButton setEnabled:YES];
    [myButton setSelected:!myButton.selected];
}
```

This works totally fine: i press the button, stuff is done on `myCustomClass`, request succeeds, button is set to inverted selected state.
But now for the other delegate method:

```
-(void)requestFailed{
    /* If the request failed i want the button to be enabled again, and it's selected  
       state stays the same */   
    NSLog(@"That gets called"); 
    [myButton setEnabled:YES];
}
```

If `requestFailed` gets called, the console prints *That gets called* as expected, but the button stays disabled... and i don't know why.
I tried other things in `requestFailed` like:

```
[myButton setHidden:YES];
```

Just to see if the reference to `myButton` is working...
And it is.

Probably i'm missing something right now, but i can't figure it out.
Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
I don't think `requestFailed` could be called from a different thread (as @gonji-dev mentioned), since both `requestSucceeded` and `requestFailed` are called from the same method.
In my `doSomeCrazyStuff` method i set up a completion block wich handles connection success and error. If an error occurred it gets handled in another class. If the connection succeeded i'm asking for HTTP status codes to decide wether `requestFailed` or `requestSucceeded` will be called.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call requestFailed? Probably you're calling this from a different thread

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in `requestFailed`after `[myButton setEnabled:YES];` and check if the target still pointing to your controller.

Comment: would not it be easier to distract the UI updates forcibly to the main-thread, rather than making assumptions of what _you don't think_, as debugging an issue is supposed not to be based on random assumptions; because if that is a background network request in your app, that must be in a background thread, and whatever they invoke it performed on that thread.

Comment: So i tried to call request failed in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }); and now the button gets enabled again... Thanks   
But i still don't know why `requestSucceeded` works and `requestFailed`did not work. Even though i don't know why, i'm happy it works ;)

Comment: @AlexanderHarl: did not see this comment until after I posted my anser. I can remove my response if you see fit. Additionally, a simple breakpoint where the log takes place would reveal the thread you are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar situation as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31952060/218152.
Are you absolutely positive that you are invoking:

```
[myButton setEnabled:YES];
```

on the main thread?

The industry standard, when manipulating the UI in response to notifications or multithreaded environment is:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // update UI
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried to call the delegate methods explicitly on the main thread and now it works for both methods. Don't know why it did not work for `requestFailed` before. But it must have had to do with it being on another thread.

Comment: Better safe than sorry: invoking UI outside of main thread is risky, and likely to crash on production.