# iOS9 - This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread -- where?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

For searching, the error message is:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

I know this means some UIKit code is called from a background thread, and I know the solution is to wrap the code in

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ <code> });`

My problem is locating where to do that, as none of the printed stack traces reference my app code.  My evidence to prove this negative is searching (command-f) in the debug output window for the name of my app; I have 24 stack traces dumped out and my app name is not in any of them, except at the top with the error message.  I can post one of them, but that doesn't seem very useful.

In the cases I am working on today, this is happening when transitioning view controllers, after `viewWillDisappear()` and before `viewWillAppear()`.  I have found parts of my code to wrap `dispatch_async()` around, but those are all handled now.  I have breakpoints and debug messages where objects relevant to the view controllers are allocated and deallocated, and they all trigger after the exception messages appear.  This is happening both on the simulator and my iOS9 iPhone, both in debug and release modes.

How can I identify the background code which is apparently modifying the UI?

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set on ObjC exceptions?  If so, does it trigger when you get this error?

Comment: yes and yes, and it triggers more than once for each stack trace triggered.

Comment: check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075072/8537648

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This code [PSPDFUIKitMainThreadGuard](https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345) causes assertions on UIKit access outside the main thread

Steps to use:

1. Add to project and compile this file without ARC
2. Move `PSPDFAssert` definition to the first of the file
3. Comment calling of `PSPDFLogError` as it is not defined
4. import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`

Your app will crash and stop with any attemption to modify any UI element from background thread

For swift use the following code: [NBUIKitMainThreadGuard](https://github.com/nrbrook/NBUIKitMainThreadGuard)

Comment: Thank you!  That nailed it immediately.  Also had to `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

Comment: what do you mean by "Move PSPDFAssert definition to the first of the file"?

Comment: That is because it gives you a compilation errors as it is defined after using it

Comment: @ngb There is a block in the code that says `#define PSPDFAssert(expression, ...) \
do { if(!(expression)) { \
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Assertion failure: %s in %s on line %s:%d. %@", #expression, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"" __VA_ARGS__]]); \
abort(); }} while(0)` Move this from it's current position to before / above `PSPDFReplaceMethodWithBlock(Class c, SEL origSEL, SEL newSEL, id block)`

Comment: Do I not need to import the file anywhere or make any kind of call?

Comment: @JeremyHicks no you don't, just add it to your project and follow the steps above to fix the compilation errors

Comment: But Still Its Showing That Warning Now What To Do @MahmoudAdam

Comment: @hardikvyas what warning?

Comment: Hi. added the files and followed the steps above. The building the application succeeded. I did not get any compilation errors. When I run the app, it breaks at `void PSPDFAssertIfNotMainThread(void) `. I am using AFNetworking to make API calls.

Comment: @GoGreen you should trace back the Stack Trace to see what is the method that causes this problem

Comment: Ok. I figured it out later. Thanks a lot @MahmoudAdam

Comment: I thank you, my mother thanks you, my mother's mother thanks you!  I was going nuts trying to track this down and you nailed it.

Comment: Note that it seems to work for me with ARC enabled. Also, use the following instead of commenting out PSPDFLogError:
`#define PSPDFLogError(expression, ...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: AWESOME routine that found in 5 minutes what two of us were looking for for hours.

Comment: I agree with Owen. This is awesome stuff and really saved me from a nightmare!!

Comment: Yep, took no longer than 5 minutes and found the problem immediately. Thank you!

Comment: I'm in XCode 7.2.1 and iOS 9.3, and the suggested code doesn't do anything.  I've even tried the variants suggested in the comments above.

Comment: [Swift Solution](https://github.com/nrbrook/NBUIKitMainThreadGuard) thanks to nrbrook.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your project scheme, and under the **Run** action, in the **Diagnostics** tab, under **Runtime API Checking**, make sure **Pause in issues** is checked. When any background UI updates occur, the app will pause.

[image]

Comment: I have Main Thread Checker set, but it doesn't stop anywhere, but I can see that error message in the console. I can't find the source of the problem because all the updates seem to run from MainThread (keyword "seem to")

Answer (score -2):

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(){
[YOUR CODE]
}
```

Comment: How/why this can answer the question?