# Xcode 7: This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode7

I'm getting this error from Xcode 7:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This
>   will cause an exception in a future release.

I fully understand what can cause this error, I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302019/getting-a-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-error) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680303/ios9-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-from-a-background-thr) one also, but I can't figure out what causing the problem in my code, I just can't find it.

Comment: When and where you are getting that error ? Can you add some code ?

Comment: [Maybe this is your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302019/getting-a-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-error) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302019/getting-a-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302019/getting-a-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-error)

Comment: "I just can't find it" Sorry to hear that, but that is not a question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302019/getting-a-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-error

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know where is it!

Comment: You should see that error *when* your code that's modifying the UI is executing. When does that error appear? What is happening in your app at the time?

Answer (score 0):

Find place where your UI is being modified on background thread and also pushing View Controller on navigation stack from background thread causes this error, posting that code on main thread will fix it.