# This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background - Why?

Tags: objective-c, game-center-leaderboard, xcode7.1

Since then I have updated Xcode(7.1) I receive (after calling the Game Center leaderboard) this error:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This
>   will cause an exception in a future release.

I have this code to call my leaderbord:

```
- (void)showLeaderboard{
    GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My application does not crash but it is annoying to have this error every time when I call the leaderbord. How I can fix this? Do you have any solutions? Thank you for helping!

Comment: And _is_ that code called on a background thread?

Comment: No, the code is on the main thread called (SKScene in the didMoveToView)

Comment: Did you try the detection method suggested here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680303/ios9-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-from-a-background-thr

Comment: @matt I have tried but maybe it is a Xcode issue