# iOS9 - Xcode 7.2 Crash Warning issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, ios-autolayout, xcode7.2

How to resolve this issue

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

I know this means some UIKit code is called from a background thread, and I know the solution is to wrap the code in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ <code> });
```

My problem is locating where to do that and How can I identify the background code which is apparently modifying the UI?

Any help is welcome..

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if you have not called some UIKit methods those may cause update constraints (like `updateConstraintsIfNeeded`, `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, etc.) in background thread? If possible, share code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This code [PSPDFUIKitMainThreadGuard](https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345) causes assertions on UIKit access outside the main thread

Steps to use:

1.Add to project and compile this file without ARC

2.Move *PSPDFAssert* definition to the first of the file

3.Comment calling of *PSPDFLogError* as it is not defined

4.import

Your app will crash and stop with any attemption to modify any UI element from background thread
see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680303/ios9-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-from-a-background-thr)