# Migrating xcode project 4.2 to xcode 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I am migrating project from xcode 4.2 to xcode 7.0 and facing exception like this...

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

and app will be crashed after few seconds.

I have removed all reference from storyboard scenes and compile source. But problem remain same.[image: Here is Exception Point]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the break point and check once you were called any thing in background thread, if yes change your thread to main

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // add your code here
});
```

check this also may be it [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680303/ios9-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-from-a-background-thr)

Comment: I am trying it but  _libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:_ here break point stop and app crashed

Comment: unfortunately I solved this problem. Thanks @ anbu.karthik for your anticipation.

Comment: @UmeshVerma -- happy to hear bro , if my answer is useful give the tick mark and upvote for the answer it is useful for in future