# Find cause of: "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread."

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have a large application that uses a number of third-party libraries and am now seeing the following error in the logs: "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes."

From what I have found here on SO, this is probably being caused by a UI element being changed on a background thread, which is triggering the autolayout. Unfortunately, we have so many UI elements being changed by so many different moving parts that I do not know the best way to find the culprit.

Can anyone tell me how can I found out what exactly is triggering the autolayout change from a background thread?

Comment: Look in any completion block. Ensure any UI code in a completion block as wrapped in `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`.

Comment: This is a massive application. There are so many completion blocks. So, so many. I hoping there is some tools-based approach somewhere because otherwise it will take forever.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680303/ios9-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-from-a-background-thr and look at the last comment (the Swift link) of the accepted answer.

Comment: That might be just what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's not a completion block, but anything that is performed in the background.
In my case it was **notifications** that where sent. I implemented **iCloud** in my app, which means that when data was edited or added on another device, the other app(s) receive an iCloud update/notification, which triggered an update of the UITableView.
The code to update the UITableView was not done in the MainThread. Adding the code as shown in the comments fixes it.