# Console shows AutoLayout Engine Warning while loading UIWebView and Crashes the app sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, autolayout

Summary:
While trying to load the URL/HTML string on `UIWebView` console shows warning like "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes." and crashes the app at some point.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Load URL/HTML String on `UIWebView`.
2. Console will show the AutoLayout engine warning.
3. App Crashed some times(Uncaught exception: Only run on the main thread!).

Expected Results:
App should not show any warning while loading `UIWebView` and should not crash the app due to that warning.

Actual Results:
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

```
    Stack:(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000188e35998 <redacted> + 148
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001884304bc objc_exception_throw + 56
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000188e358c8 <redacted> + 0
        3   Foundation                          0x00000001899a3da0 <redacted> + 192
        4   Foundation                          0x00000001899a3b00 <redacted> + 76
        5   Foundation                          0x0000000189808548 <redacted> + 108
        6   Foundation                          0x00000001899a2788 <redacted> + 104
        7   UIKit                               0x000000018ebbc76c <redacted> + 1464
        8   QuartzCore                          0x000000018c0e0d6c <redacted> + 148
        9   QuartzCore                          0x000000018c0d5aac <redacted> + 292
        10  QuartzCore                          0x000000018c0d596c <redacted> + 32
        11  QuartzCore                          0x000000018c0554fc <redacted> + 252
        12  QuartzCore                          0x000000018c07c7c4 <redacted> + 512
        13 

 QuartzCor
```

iOS Version:
`iOS 10 beta 1`

Xcode version:
`Xcode 8 beta`

**This issue has been resolved in iOS 10 beta2.**

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: And do indicate where it crashes as well.

Comment: This issue has been resolved in iOS 10 beta2. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28321213/6521116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was happening in `iOS 10 beta1` and I filed an issue in Apple Bug report with sample project. Now the issue has been resolved in `iOS 10 beta 2`.

Thanks!