# How to easily investigate 'This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading

I have this message in the debugger window:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can
>   lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

I know what it means and I know how to fix it, but the problem is that I have a lot of threads fired in different parts of the application and is difficult to get a full stack trace.
The app is not crashing, as it is treated as a warning.

How can I pause/halt the application when this occurs, so I can see exactly what is going on there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37421595/1801544 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/39712843/1801544 ?

Comment: THANK YOU @Larme - Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, since I already knew how to fix it. The question was how to trace it better.

Comment: The previously linked answers are from this question. Feel free to up vote them. I know the question is not totally a duplicate, but the useful answers (explaining why, and others explaining how to find them) are there.

Comment: I have already done that (up voted). But I feel that this kind of Q/A should just be separate. Otherwise, this question will be closed or will remained unanswered.

Comment: It's up to you, we gave each others our opinion on how the two questions are duplicate. I won't "steal/plagiat" the others answers personally. This doesn't forbid you to edit your question and point out the solution from the other question in case others also vote for a duplicate of your question (this way, the answer will remain clearly visible and not only in comment).