# When I run my application In simulator it shows some autolayout errors

Tags: swift3, autolayout

> his application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can
>   lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Comment: You should post some code also.

Comment: Post the Error logs also, logs are descriptive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28302019/6521116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

It needs to be placed inside a different thread that allows the UI to update as soon as execution of thread function complete

```
DispatchQueue.main.async 
{
   // Update UI
}
```

Comment: In dispatch I added self. Tableview.reloaddata()

Comment: do you check, which line of your code give this error by placed breakpoint on your code?, may be the error is generate at elsewhere...