# How to solve: This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread

Tags: ios, xcode, background, autolayout, ios-autolayout

This error is logged to the console when some part of the code is changing UI items from other threads than the main thread. But how can I find where it does this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Main problem with "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread" is that it seem to be logged a long time after the actual problem occurs, this can make it very hard to troubleshoot.

I managed to solve the issue by creating three symbolic breakpoints.

Debug > Breakpoints > Create Symbolic Breakpoint...

**Breakpoint 1:**

- Symbol: `-[UIView setNeedsLayout]`
- Condition: `!(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]`

**Breakpoint 2:**

- Symbol: `-[UIView layoutIfNeeded]`
- Condition: `!(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]`

**Breakpoint 3:**

- Symbol: `-[UIView updateConstraintsIfNeeded]`
- Condition: `!(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]`

With these breakpoints, you can easily get a break on the actual line where you incorrectly call UI methods on non-main thread.

Comment: Is There a way I can do this in Visual Studio?

Comment: Thank you so much! My app kept logging 3 different "modifying from a background thread" messages but they didn't actually show up until at least 10 seconds later - after a segue to a different ViewController, even though the code there doesn't even actively use background threads. Would you mind posting your answer (or at least linking to it) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28302019/2016165) too? It's the question that shows up as the first search result and people also keep linking to it. I wouldn't have found yours if I hadn't googled `!(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]`.

Comment: Did post it there also now @Neph.

Comment: Great info, spent hours finding the issue and this pin pointed it for me.  Thanks!